# Отмена перенос строки в HTML, чтобы убрать лишний пробел

Tags: php, html, css

Мой html-код генерится php-скриптом. Если знак препинания обернут в отдельный тег и стоит на следующей строке, то между этим знаком препинания и предшествующим словом появляется нежелательный пробел:

> текст1; **текст2 ;** текст3; текст4; ...

[image: см. скриншот]

Можно ли как-то отменить перенос строки в html-коде и добиться, чтобы у пользователя в браузере текст и знаки препинания отображались без пробелов?

```
@if ('' != $wmeaning->multi_translation)
    <span class='tvb_wmmt'>{{ $wmeaning->multi_translation }}</span><span class='semicolon'>;</span>
@endif

@foreach ($bridge->translationAdditions as $translationAddition)
    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_addition))
        <span class='tvb_ta'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_addition }}</span>
    @endif

    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_comment))
        <span class='tvb_tc'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_comment }}</span>
    @endif

    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_operand))
        <span class='tvb_to'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_operand }}</span>
    @endif

    <span class='semicolon'>;</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: приведите код, который генерит html. Или попробуйте дополнительно обработать ответ от метода, который генерирует разметку. Что-то типа `$html = str_replace('</span>\n<span>', '</span><span>', $obj->genHtml());`

Comment: А какие стили навешаны на класс `semicolon`? может там паддинги или марджины или еще чего

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не, это ж стандартный пробел между inline элементами

Comment: А почему у вас в одном случае разметка генерируется с переносом, а в других (выше и ниже примера на картинке) без переноса, хотя `;` так же в отдельном теге?

Comment: Я использую фреймворк Laravel и его шаблонизатор blade. Не уверен, что там можно регулярками убирать эти пробелы. Код из вьюхи ларавела см. в описании к вопросу.

Comment: Насколько понимаю, вы добавили код, которым вставляете данные в шаблон. А как выглядит сам шаблон?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD 3**. Стоящей на отдельной строке `;` давать другой класс `<span class='semicolon-alone'>;</span>`, которому назначить `margin-left: -10px;`. Значение подобрать под размер шрифта.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 40px;
}
.semicolon-alone {
  margin-left: -10px;
)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text">text</span><span class="semicolon">;</span>
  <br>
  <span class="text">text</span>
  <span class="semicolon-alone">;</span>
</div>
```

**UPD 2**. С учётом комментариев к ответу предлагаю ещё три варианта.

1) Узнать, как вставлять более серьёзные куски PHP, собирать строку без лишних пробелов и выводить её целиком. Не работал с Laravel. Нужно нечто в таком духе:

```
$tmp = "";

if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_addition)) {
 $tmp .= "<span class='tvb_ta'>" . $translationAddition->translation_addition . "</span>";
}

if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_comment)) {
 $tmp .= "<span class='tvb_tc'>" . $translationAddition->translation_comment . "</span>";
}

if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_operand)) {
 $tmp .= "<span class='tvb_to'>" .  $translationAddition->translation_operand . "</span>';
}

$tmp .= "<span class='semicolon'>;</span>";
```

2) Закрывать комментарии по условию. Будет много, очень много комментариев.

```
@if ('' != $wmeaning->multi_translation)
    <span class='tvb_wmmt'>{{ $wmeaning->multi_translation }}</span><span class='semicolon'>;</span>
@endif

@foreach ($bridge->translationAdditions as $translationAddition)
    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_addition))
        <span class='tvb_ta'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_addition }}</span><!--
    @endif

    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_comment))
        @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_addition))
            -->
        @endif
        <span class='tvb_tc'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_comment }}</span><!--
    @endif

    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_operand))
        @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_addition) || !empty($translationAddition->translation_comment))
            -->
        @endif
        <span class='tvb_to'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_operand }}</span><!--
    @endif

    --><span class='semicolon'>;</span>
@endforeach
```

3) Обнулять размер шрифта только у содержимого цикла. Для этого заворачивать его в дополнительный спан.

```
.kill-the-space {
  font-size: 0;
}
.text,
.semicolon {
  font-size: 20px;
)

@foreach ($bridge->translationAdditions as $translationAddition)
    <span class='kill-the-space'>

    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_addition))
        <span class='tvb_ta'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_addition }}</span>
    @endif

    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_comment))
        <span class='tvb_tc'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_comment }}</span>
    @endif

    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_operand))
        <span class='tvb_to'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_operand }}</span>
    @endif

    <span class='semicolon'>;</span></span>
@endforeach
```

---

**UPD**. Предлагаю добавить в ваш код HTML-комментарии, чтобы спрятать просвет между спанами:

```
@if ('' != $wmeaning->multi_translation)
    <span class='tvb_wmmt'>{{ $wmeaning->multi_translation }}</span><span class='semicolon'>;</span>
@endif

@foreach ($bridge->translationAdditions as $translationAddition)
    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_addition))
        <span class='tvb_ta'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_addition }}</span><!--
    @endif

    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_comment))
        <span class='tvb_tc'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_comment }}</span><!--
    @endif

    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_operand))
        <span class='tvb_to'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_operand }}</span><!--
    @endif

    --><span class='semicolon'>;</span>
@endforeach
```

Если программа такое не переварит, то клонировать точку с запятой:

```
@if ('' != $wmeaning->multi_translation)
    <span class='tvb_wmmt'>{{ $wmeaning->multi_translation }}</span><span class='semicolon'>;</span>
@endif

@foreach ($bridge->translationAdditions as $translationAddition)
    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_addition))
        <span class='tvb_ta'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_addition }}</span><span class='semicolon'>;</span>
    @endif

    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_comment))
        <span class='tvb_tc'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_comment }}</span><span class='semicolon'>;</span>
    @endif

    @if (!empty($translationAddition->translation_operand))
        <span class='tvb_to'>{{ $translationAddition->translation_operand }}</span><span class='semicolon'>;</span>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

А вот так можно заткнуть дыру с помощью стилей:

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}
.text,
.semicolon {
  font-size: 20px;
)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text">text1</span><span class="semicolon">;</span>
  <br>
  <span class="text">text2</span> <span class="semicolon">;</span>
  <br>
  <span class="text">text3</span>
  <span class="semicolon">;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Abaza Дополнил ответ с учетом добавленного вами кода.

Comment: Прикинул вариант с комментариями. Но он не прокатит, т.к. если одновременно сработают два и более условия, то начало комментария после первого условия распространится на 2-й блок.

Comment: Тоже самое касается варианта с клонированием `<span class="semicolon">;</span>` - ведь если все 3 условия вернут `true`, то символ `;` будет стоять после каждого из них, а мне нужно чтобы он ставился один раз в конце, после отработки всех условий

Comment: Вариант со стилями тоже не подходит, т. к. в классе `container` у меня очень много различных дочерних элементов и для каждого тогда придется выставлять индивидуальный **font-size**, иначе теги с содержимым перестают отображаться. Я в примере к вопросу для простоты все лишнее убрал, иначе код бы занимал слишком много места.

Comment: @Abaza Добавил еще три варианта в ответ.

Comment: Я использую шаблонизатор Laravel-а. Он устроен так, что в него передается переменная - массив (в моем случае многомерный массив объектов), который внутри шаблонизатора `foreach`-ами раскидывается по `span`-ам. Количество уровней вложенности - 7. Т. о., сборка правильных строк путем конкатенации нужных `span`-в повлечет за собой отказ (частичный) от возможностей встроенного шаблонизатора (что в моем случае не удобно) ценой усложнения кода вьюх. На выходе эта задача конечно будет решена, но цена для меня получится как бы не приемлемая :)

Comment: Касательно использования комментариев с дополнительными проверками. По началу я подумал, что это решит задачу. Но, к сожалению, из-за многомерности обрабатываемого массива, большое количество вложенных уровней при проверке рано или поздно приводит к ситуации, когда в открытый комментарий, встраивается блок с другим комментарием. Из-за этого, ранее открытый комментарий, как бы закрывается вложенным комментарием и на выходе не получаю то, что хотел бы.

Comment: @Abaza Я правильно понимаю, что между тремя блоками `@if ...@endif`, которые вы опубликовали, стоят ещё фрагменты кода, которые вы не показали?

Comment: Да, вы совершенно правильно поняли - количество уровней вложенности - 7 штук. Я в вопросе показал только фрагмент кода, который примерно на самом глубоком уровне вложенности. При этом я рассчитывал, что разрывы строки в исходном html-коде можно как-то отменить какими-либо простыми шагами

Comment: @Abaza А вариант с заворачиванием строки в спан, уничтожающий пробелы между спанами внутри себя?

Comment: @Abaza  Ещё вариант: Стоящей на отдельной строке `;` давать другой класс `<span class='semicolon-alone'>;</span>`, которому назначить `margin-left: -10px;`. Значение подобрать под размер шрифта. Добавил сниппет в начало ответа.

Comment: вариант с заворачиванием строки в спан не подошел. Причина в той же многоуровневой вложенности условий. В зависимости от срабатываемых условий класс `.kill-the-space` либо решает проблему, либо наоборот - создает съедая нужный пробел. А вот решение с `margin-left` похоже решает проблему. В моем случае подошло `-4px`. По крайней мере, визуально выглядит нормально. Конечно, при копи-пасте текста скажем в блокнот, этот пробел опять портит всю картину :) В любом случае, спасибо вам за помощь. Я пока остановился на варианте с `margin-left: -4px;`

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал такой вариант, и неожиданно работает. Вот только я не знаю насколько валидно так делать :) Думаю, что для корректного отображения в общей массе текста, каждый такой кусок кода нужно оборачивать в дополнительную обёртку с `clear:both`.

```css
.text {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text">text1</span><span class="semicolon">;</span>
  <br>
  <span class="text">text2</span> <span class="semicolon">;</span>
  <br>
  <span class="text">text3</span>
  <span class="semicolon">;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробовал **float: left**, но он не подходит, т. к. он прибивает символ `;` в самый левый край div-а, т. е. текст, после которого должен идти символ `;`, оказывается правее это точки с запятой

Comment: @Abaza, у меня  `float` не для точки с запятой, а для текста перед :)

Comment: да я ошибся. Но потом проверил прописав правильно. Все равно не устраивает, т. к. там слева приходится размещать много разных элементов, которые тоже тогда прибиваются влево. Получается что-то вроде вот этого:
`text0text1; text2;`
В описании выше `text0` в зависимости от результат проверки блока `if(){}` может как присутствовать так и отсутсвовать